# Is there any protocol for reverse traceroute?

Tags: networking, routes, protocols, nat

Say i'm communicating with a computer A in a remote network .

Is it possible to know what are the hops that he is going through?

In other word, is it possible to detect what is computer A route to my computer?

I know that A might have a various routes to my computer , it just want to find a route. My whole problem begins with that fact that some networks  "hides" there inside computer ( like NAT ) and just give you the gateway ip.

(I'm not talking about my route to his computer that can be easly achived by traceroute)

thanks!

Comment: The whole purpose of NAT is to hide that.... So I guess that no (or I misundersdood the question)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - yea , thats might be a problem. But I'm looking for some kind of hueristic . I want to retrive maxmimum information possible

Answer (score 2):

The IP option [Record Route](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) asks routers along the way to include their address in the datagram so the route can be tracked. The trick is, many routers and firewalls are not keen on giving out this information and `DROP` packets with this option set. And, you'd have to get the remote peer to set the flag, so it would only be useful if you're in control of the software on the remote peer too.